# Get all SQL columns as String with SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have table with several columns, however I don't know what type each one will be before receiving them.  I'd like to print the values of all of them out without having to check the type of each column and using a switch block to make the appropriate cast.

I have the following code:

```
string c0 = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
string c1 = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
```

however this isn't quite working as expected.

For example, if the columns are coming back as types `{int, byte[]}`, the code above will yield:

```
c0 = "719231" // as expected
c1 = "System.Byte[]" // trying to get "0x728AEBF720"
```

Although my specific question

Is there a clean way to do this I've missed, or will I have to have a bunch of switching logic based on the type like the following?

```
if (o.GetType() == typeof(byte[]))
    return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(o as byte[]);
else if (... more chained special cases)
    return o.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, if this is for generic table structures you'll have to handle types that cant be converted to string yourself.

ie `byte[]`
you can get the type via

```
reader.GetFieldType(column)
```

also be sure to check for nulls